# Looking for a open source web testing automation framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, functional-testing

Guys I am looking for Web Testing Generic Automation Framework which can be used to do automation testing of various web based applications .Looking for C# based framework as that is the language I am more familiar with. But any other language framework will also do and it should not use any proprietary/licensed language.
Framework should have some open source and free of cost license model.

I searched for selenium based framework on Google and SO. But could not come with any which have source code available. It will be good if the framework encapsulates all the functionality provided by Selenium WebDriver and/or Selenium RC and empower the functional tester to create and maintain test in human readable scripts.

**Requirements of the framework:**

The framework code should avoid hard coding of test steps. My idea is to  maintain the test scripts outside the automation framework code , so that they can be easily be modified if needed. The framework should read through the step tables and the data tables and run the test accordingly.

If there is no such framework available now right then we can collectively build such a framework in a open source community model.

P.S.
I have read a little about Hermes Framework and Robot Framework, but not yet tried them, any help is welcome.

Comment: Robot is a BDD framework; that's NOT what you are looking for.  I've been working on a framework on Github but I am not done with it yet and its not ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good side of this problem: there are a lot of flexible tools and approaches, you can get together and build a flexible, reliable and robust test automation framework.
The hard part is: yes, there is no “out of box” solution, and you’ll need to find and put together lots of tools in order to solve this test automation puzzle.
What I would recommend:

1. First you need to choose a unit-test test framework. This is a tool which helps to identify separate methods in code as tests, so you can run them together or separately and get the run results, such as pass or fail.
   My personal opinion, is that the testing tool – **MS-Test** – which ships with Visual Studio 2013 (and also Express Edition) is good enough.  Another alternatives are: **[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org)** or **[Gallio Icarus](https://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/)**
2. All unit-testing frameworks includes a mechanism for doing assertions inside the test. The capability of assertions class depends on given unit-testing framework. Here, I would like to recommend a popular library which works great for the entire unit testing framework.
   This is **[Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions)** (also available from NuGet repository).
3. That’s a hard moment. You need to decide: are you going to use the PageObject approach in order to build your test automation framework, or you are going to choose  simpler approach, without heavy utilization of the Object Oriented Programming.
   Properly designed Page Objects makes your test automation code much maintainable. Utilizing the OOP – you can do a magic in your code: write less to do more. Although, such approach requires more skill.
   Here are a good articles on this topic:
   [Maintainable Automated UI Tests](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/maintainable-automated-ui-tests/)
   And this one:
   [Tips to Avoid Brittle UI Tests](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/tips-to-avoid-brittle-ui-tests/)
4. The alternative to the PageObject is a scripted approach. This approach can be also successful and requires less time to start.
   **[Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu)** is a good and usable example of such framework for Selenium Web Driver.
5. All the popular unit-testing frameworks support data-driven tests. The best support is in NUnit – you can run/re-run and see the tests generated for individual data row in the tests tree. 
   MS-Test supports reading data from different data-sources: text files, excel, mssql etc., but it is not possible to re-run the test for individual data row. Although, there is a hack for this – **[Ms-Test Rows](https://github.com/dzhariy/mstest-rows)**.
   For my data-driven tests, I am using a great library – **[Linq to Excel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)**
   I have a lot more to say. There are so many approaches to build test automation framework – and there is no ready solution yet.

I am trying to build one according to my testing methodology – [SWD.Starter](https://github.com/dzhariy/SWD.Starter) . 
This project is still on its early development stages. But, at least, probably you’ll find a few tips how to build and organize the test automation code.

Comment: I am going though your projects , will update how things are going in next few weeks .

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented https://github.com/leblancmeneses/RobustHaven.IntegrationTests based on my prior experience on large projects "trying" to implement full end to end testing.

I've been using this and and have a lot of useful extensions for general selenium, angularjs, and kendo ui work.  Since this framework is not obtrusive you could just use these extensions without using anything else.

I'm using this on my latest project and everyone is loving it.

---

There are a lot of bdd/spec frameworks (specflow, mspec, nspec, storyq)  to help wire the behavior of your system to tests.

What I've learned:

- make it frictionless for any .net developer/tester to begin writing/running tests.

  - Most fail here because it requires installing additional pluggins into visual studio.
  - mine uses the standard nunit
  - Logically you would think that a feature is a class file and scenarios are [Test] methods - to support some of these frameworks they make each scenario a class file.
- use the original spec to create stubs of your tests - hopefully readable code

  - I used spec flow back in 2010 - so things might have changed.  I generated my tests from my bdd document. A year later when I went to add more tests and update existing tests,  I felt I wasted a lot of time with ceremony than writing code I really wanted - I stopped using it.
  - My approach uses t4 to generate stubs - developer has a choice to generate from feature file, for a specific scenario or don't use generated code at all.
- how is state shared across steps / nested steps

  - most use `dictionary<string,object>` to help you separate data from being hardcoded in your tests accessed from a context object.
  - mine uses viewmodels and pointers to those viewmodels - if your using something like angularjs you are using viewmodels in your server side display/editor templates and in angularjs controller so why not reuse these in your tests!
- start early with CI - make development transparent

  - My project has ResultDiff that given the nunit testresult.xml file, folder location to your gherkin feature files, and output json file;   Read description on why this is important on the screenshot: https://github.com/leblancmeneses/RobustHaven.IntegrationTests#step-5-ci-setup-resultdiff

Example:
Modified means business and developers have a mismatch of Gherkin statements - did something change that we need to talk about?

What is missing? a dashboard to render the .json file created by ResultDiff.  It's on my backlog.....
With a centralized dashboard that supports multiple environments(branches of your code) this dashboard will serve all stakeholders (business, developers) what is the status of features being developed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework named "omelet" which is built in java on top of testng for selenium,
For cross browser multi-parallel testing , it easily blends with your CI tools and have some cool reporting features with step level reports

Running your test cases on BrowserStack and Grid was never so easy as with omelet with few config changes.

if you want to give it a try then do follow the **5 min tutorial** available on the website, there is archetype available on maven central + there are many more features available

Stable version is 1.0.4 and we are currently looking for people to contribute to project.

Documentation over [here](http://springer-opensource.github.io/omelet/)

Github [link](https://github.com/springer-opensource/omelet)